# php defining a variable type vs not defining

Tags: php, performance, variables, types

I'm wondering if there is any difference in defining the type of a variable in php vs not defining the variable type.

```
$count = (integer) 0;
```

vs

```
$count = 0;
```

wich of these is better, performance- and practical wise

Comment: `$count = (integer) 0;` you define nothing here.

Comment: oh, what is the purpose of (integer) than?

Comment: You cast 0 to type integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference at all in particularly this case, since 0 is already an integer. This only makes the code less readable, but doesn't "assign" a type for the variable.

However, if instead of 0 there was another variable and you want to ensure that the value of $count is integer, it would make sense to have `$count = (int)$other_var;`